# Bash - dirname not working with substitution

Tags: bash, find, dirname

When using `find` with `$(dirname {})`, it always just outputs "." as the dirname. E.g. for:

```
find . -name \*.h -exec echo {} \; -exec echo $(dirname {}) \;
```

outputs:

```
./folder/folder.h
.
./folder/sub_folder/sub_folder.h
.
./test.h
.
```

But I would expect this:

```
./folder/folder.h
./folder
./folder/sub_folder/sub_folder.h
./folder/sub_folder
./test.h
.
```

Interestingly, creating a new shell for each find generates the correct output:

```
find . -name \*.h -exec sh -c 'echo $0; echo $(dirname $0);' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line gives what you want:

```
find . -name *.h -print -exec dirname {} \;
```

Comment: True, what is the dollar sign doing which prevents the command from working properly?
Also, how can it be used with other variables e.g. $SOME_DIR/$(dirname {})?

Answer (score 2):

After having tested the above command through a script, it has been observed that `$(dirname {})` is expanded to current directory `.`'.

```
mkdir -p test1/test2
touch test1/test2/tests.h
find . -name \*.h -exec echo {} \; -exec echo $(dirname {}) \;
./test1/test2/tests.h
.

echo "find . -name \*.h -exec echo {} \; -exec echo $(dirname {}) \;" > checkh.sh

bash -vx checkh.sh

find . -name \*.h -exec echo {} \; -exec echo . \;
+ find . -name '*.h' -exec echo '{}' ';' -exec echo . ';'
./test1/test2/tests.h
.
.
```

That's why the output is always displayed as only `.` current directory.

So, use your mini-script `sh -c` style or [Kent's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58911805/bash-dirname-not-working-with-substitution/58912205#58912205).

A slight modification from your command will also work, i.e., put `echo` inside command substitution:

```
find . -name \*.h -exec echo {} \; -exec $(echo dirname {}) \;
./test1/test2/tests.h
./test1/test2
```

Test case on the modification is as follows:

```
echo "find . -name \*.h -exec echo {} \; -exec $(echo dirname {}) \;" > checkh2.sh 
bash -vx checkh2.sh 
find . -name \*.h -exec echo {} \; -exec dirname {} \;
+ find . -name '*.h' -exec echo '{}' ';' -exec dirname '{}' ';'
./test1/test2/tests.h
./test1/test2
```

Answer (score 0):

You might actually want to use this:

```
find . -name '*.h' -type f -printf "%p\n%h\n"
```

When you look at `man find` under the `printf` format section, you will notice that there are a plethora of useful flags.